# Encrypted home folder and email

Tags: email, encryption, dovecot

I'd like to encrypt my home folder in CentOS.  I notice Dovecot has created directories and files under ~/mail.  If I encrypt, will my email stop working (remote access over imap and smtp)?

Comment: @Christopher - so daemons such as dovecot can still use the data?  I think my confusion is that, dovecot would not have my decryption key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your unencrypted directory is available only when you are logged in, it's a fake filesystem provided by the decryption program. When you're logged out, the fake (decrypted) filesystem does not exist. `dovecot`, `at`, `cron` cannot see it.

Reconfigure `dovecot` to only use files/dirs that exist while you're logged out.